# jQuery Validation Single Message for each rule

Tags: jquery-validate, rules, message

I have an application with several input fields that have the **required** jQuery validation rule.

If the fields are invalid I want to highlight them all however I only want a single message for required to be displayed at the top of the page.

I am displaying the messages on the top of the page with the `errorLabelContainer` attribute.

What is the best way to limit each rule to display only a single message?

Answer (score 0):

When processing the validation of input filed's you could create a new String, each time there is a validation error append the string with the validation error from each input field. Then set the inner html of errorLabelContainer to the string value.

Comment: I was thinking that I would have to manually select distinct error messages from a list generated by the JQuery Validate plug-in. I was hoping there was a cleaner way such as rule attribute to define the maximum number error messages for the rule. Thank you for the quick response.